# Temporarily swap the device sensors axes

Tags: android, android-sensors, gyroscope, axes, digital-compass

I'd like to create an app that can temporarily swap the XYZ device sensors axes such as the gyroscope, compass, accelerometer, etc. (i.e. make the device believe that X axis is Z, north is south, right is left, up is down, etc...).
As long as this app is loaded, all other apps will believe the fake sensors data, the ability to turn it on/off directly from the notification bar, if possible, I'd like this to work without root!
If anyone can help or can point me to an existing solution, I'd be very grateful! I would even be willing to pay a reasonable price if you can develop that for me!